# Proving intersection of empty set is the set of all sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

In an exercise, it asks to prove $\bigcap \varnothing$ is equal to the set of all sets.  I understand that there are many proofs online but I have a specific question (mostly regarding mathematical logic) regarding my proof.

From my understanding, given a set $S$ (where all of its elements are also sets), $x \in \bigcap S \iff \forall \, Y\in S, x \in Y$.

Now I will try and show the set of all sets is contained in $\bigcap \varnothing$.  Let $x$ be an arbitrary set - now $x \in \bigcap \varnothing \iff \forall \, Y\in \varnothing, x \in Y$.  My question is why the statement $\forall \, Y\in \varnothing, x \in Y$ vacuously true?  From my understanding, a statement is vacuously true in the case of an implication (ie. $p \implies q$ where $p$ is false) but I fail to see how $\forall \, Y\in \varnothing, x \in Y$ can be written in an implication (I tried writing it in the form $\forall Y: Y \in \varnothing \implies x \in Y$ but this is not the same statement)

Comment: "but this is not the same statement" Yes, it is.

Comment: Ah I was unaware of this - so is this true in any situation? So for example, if the statement is $\forall x \in S: P(x)$ where $P(x)$ is some property of $x$, is this the same as $\forall x: x \in S \implies P(x)$

Comment: Yes. Maybe there are some systems of logic where only one version is allowed, but for most mathematicians there is no difference. And it is exactly the reason why $\forall x\in\emptyset:P(x)$ is vacuously true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall Y \in \varnothing \; P(Y)$ means 
$\forall Y \; (Y \in \varnothing \implies P(Y))$.
But $Y \in \varnothing$ is always false, making the implication $Y \in \varnothing \implies P(Y)$ true.

Comment: What is $P(Y)$ mean?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\emptyset$ has no elements, each unary predicate $\varphi$ satisfies $\forall Y\in\emptyset(\varphi(Y))$. In this case, our predicate is $x\in Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the negation of $\forall Y\in\varnothing, x\in Y$. It is $\exists Y\in\varnothing, x\notin Y$. The latter is false, because there is no element in the empty set. Hence the original proposition was true.